# Rivals For Catan – How do you draw a card when playing the Library

Tags: rivals-for-catan

In Rivals For Catan, the Library card says that:
"When you build the Library, you may immediately choose a card from a draw stack."

Does this mean that you look through a draw stack and select which card to take? Or do you take the top card from a draw stack of your choice?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "choose a card" indicates you may **look through a stack**; otherwise, they would have been more specific and said to take a card from the top, or take a card at random, or something like that.  Admittedly, they could have been a little clearer.

According to [this BoardGameGeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/655866/building-the-library), [Professor Easy's Interactive Online Tutorial](http://www.catan.com/servicenews/277-prof-easys-interactive-online-tutorial-for-the-rivals-for-catan-now-available.html) has an example where one of the players is shown using the library to look through a stack.  I must have clicked 100 "Next" links and didn't see that, but I spaced out near the end.

Comment: Oh hey, that's your post over on BGG that I linked to, looks like you got the same answer there.